# Getting jquery selectors using chrome dev tools

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to use chrome dev tools under the condole tab to find a jquery path/selectors. I have the following HTML:

```
 <p class="lead">More complex content example:</p>
<div id="tab" class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
<a href="#prices2" class="btn btn-large btn-info active" data-toggle="tab">Prices</a>
 <a href="#features2" id="2" name="button1" class="btn btn-large btn-info" data-  toggle="tab">Features</a>
 <a href="#requests2" id="2" name="button2" class="btn btn-large btn-info" data-toggle="tab">Requests</a>
```

I tries looking for the 'a' selector using:

```
$ .a
undefined
$a
ReferenceError: $a is not defined
$.a
undefined
$[a]
ReferenceError: a is not defined
$(a)
ReferenceError: a is not defined
$[a]
ReferenceError: a is not defined
$.[a]
SyntaxError: Unexpected token [
$.(a)
```

as you can see , its not working. What  do I need to to to find the correct selector path?

Comment: so, put it in a string, like `$('a')`

Comment: have you tried $("a")?

Comment: @kalley jinx you owe me a soda

Comment: @underbar ok...where do I send it?

Comment: [FacePalm @everything] The question ... the comments ... just [FacePalm!]

Comment: @SpYk3HH you know if we are doing something that is wrong or laughable then we'd love to hear about what it is so we could learn and grow. rather then you just being judgmental

Comment: @underbar nothing wrong, just laughing at the jinx comments, lol. And just [FacePalm] about the question all together. I didn't answer, because you two already had. It was just amusing, that's all.

Comment: @SpYk3HH ahh alright my mistake, I thought you were criticizing the answers. but I agree this is a pretty facepalmable (new favorite adjective) post, but on a site like SO it's bound to happen

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$` is a function, just like any other function

```
function sum(value1, value2) {
    return value1 + value2;
}
```

it is called like

```
var result = sum(2, 4);
```

Therefor, [selecting a element using jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) would look like this:

```
var result = $("a");
```

Comment: Thanks Guys, I know its basic but I was pooling my hair out - Bill

Comment: You're welcome. For people starting with jQuery it might be frustrating to understand what the `$` would mean. So I think it's a legit question.

Comment: `$.toString()` returns 
`"function(a,b){return new n.fn.init(a,b)}"`